# tmap facetmap not working for tm_fill but does for tm_symbols

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to use tmap to make some interactive plots for a global data set. The file map.temp is of classes `sf` and `data.frame`. It has four columns - `FPU`, `value`, `year`, and `geometry`. I want to make facets for year, which is a character variable with three unique values - 2005, 2050, and 2080.

`head(map.temp)` returns

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -179.1667 ymin: 39.66666 xmax: 179.8333 ymax: 71.41666
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
      FPU year                       geometry value
1 ALB_ALB 2005 MULTIPOLYGON (((20.08333 39...  2494
2 ALB_ALB 2050 MULTIPOLYGON (((20.08333 39...  2565
3 ALB_ALB 2080 MULTIPOLYGON (((20.08333 39...  1906
4 ALK_USA 2005 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179 51.166...    NA
5 ALK_USA 2050 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179 51.166...    NA
6 ALK_USA 2080 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179 51.166...    NA
```

The `tm_shape` code below has three commented out lines; one each for `tm_polygons`, `tm_fill`, and `tm_symbols`. If these are uncommented out and the code run separately each produces three graphs, one for each year. I expect tm_fill and tm_polygons to fill the FPU polygons with colors, but they do it only for year = 2080. If the tm_symbols line is uncommented, it has results (circles whose size is relative to value) for each year. The test.RDS file is available [here](https://github.com/GeraldCNelson/nutmod/blob/master/test.RDS). My main question is how to have the facets for 2005 and 2050 be colored using `tm_fill`.

```
library(tmap)
map.temp <- readRDS("test.RDS")
title <- "Maize rainfed yield <br> (mt/ha)"
legend_title <- "(mt/ha)"
breaks <- c(1.0, 2139.2, 4277.5, 6415.8, 8554)
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(map.temp) + 
 #   tm_polygons(col = "value", breaks = breaks, title = legend_title) +
 #   tm_fill(col = "value", title = legend_title)  +
    tm_borders() +
 #   tm_symbols(col = "black", border.col = "black", size = "value", title.col = legend_title) +
    tm_facets(by = "year",  nrow = 3, free.coords = FALSE, sync = TRUE) + 
    tm_layout(title = title) +
    tm_view(view.legend.position  = c("left", "bottom"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work. I am not a connoisseur of `tmap`, but have you tried to set `free.coords` to `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` in `tm_facets`? It did the trick for me.

I also think that `tm_borders`, `tm_fill` and `tm_polygons` are somehow redundant in this case, so I kept only `tm_polygons`.

Here are my edits to your code that should fix your issue:

```
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(map.temp) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "value", breaks = breaks, title = legend_title) +
  tm_symbols(col = "black", border.col = "black", size = "value", title.col = legend_title) +
  tm_facets(by = "year",  nrow = 3, free.coords = TRUE, sync = TRUE) + # set free.coords to TRUE
  tm_layout(title = title) +
  tm_view(view.legend.position  = c("left", "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: The change to free.coords = TRUE did the trick. But the terminology seems backward. I want each of the facets to have the same legend which implies to me that the free.coords should be FALSE. The Help text is "logical. If the by argument is specified, should each map has its own coordinate ranges? By default TRUE, unless facets are shown in as different layers (as.layers = TRUE)" which is ambiguous.

Comment: Hi @JerryN. I see your point. Maybe is indeed not that clear. Took me a while to figure it out as well. However, I also do not see the connection/implication between having the same legend and `free.coords = FALSE` or `TRUE`. My mental representation is that the legend is related to `fill` aesthetic not to `x` or `y` (longitude, latitude), so has nothing to do with anything related to whatever trickles down from coordinates, like position, coordinate ranges or aspect ratio.

Comment: I like your mental representation discussion about the difference between legend values and `free.coords`. But I'm still having trouble with what `free.coords` actually does. And as you may have seen in a different SO question of mine, it appears that the color fill of the polygons is correct but the values and FPU names that appear when you click on a polygon are wrong. In your output, if you click on Greenland do you get a popup that says AMU_RUS for the FPU name? That is the name of a polygon in Russia. And is the value the same in the maps for all three years?

Comment: Hi @JerryN. I see your concern. That is indeed something I didn't check. I do not know how to solve that with `tmap`, but I gave it a try with `mapview` to your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991624/5193830)