# R tmap tm_facet assigns values to the wrong location

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to use tm_facets to display data (in this case on maize yields) in 2005, 2050, and 2080. The test.RDS file is available [here](https://github.com/GeraldCNelson/nutmod/blob/master/test.RDS).

```
library(tmap)
map.temp <- readRDS("test.RDS")
title <- "Maize rainfed yield <br> (mt/ha)"
legend_title <- "(mt/ha)"
breaks <- c(1.0, 2139.2, 4277.5, 6415.8, 8554)
tm_shape(map.temp) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "value", title = legend_title) +
  tm_facets(by = "year") +
  tm_layout(main.title = title) +
  tm_view(view.legend.position  = c("left", "bottom"))
```

The code above does this, but displays the data in the wrong polygon and wrong years. To see this, run the script and click the dark red area in northeast Canada. The popup in all three maps says AMR_RUS with value of 5,634, but the colors are different. View the map.temp file (I'm using Rstudio to do all of this). Filter on FPU with AMR_RUS. The 2005 value is 6,047, 2050 is 5634 and 2080 is 4406 (climate change will reduce yields in this area). Next look at the first couple of entries in the geometry column. The lat long coordinates are for a region along the Chinese-Russian border. The Amur River makes up that border and AMR_RUS FPU (food production unit) is to the north of the Amur River in Russia.

Is the problem with my code or data or the tm_facet function in tmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't figure out a solution with `tmap`, and not sure why is doing that misplacing of polygon names and values in the popup. **UPDATE:** seems that this was a `tmap` bug, which was immediately fixed - see [tmap issue 268](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/268).

I know you asked for `tmap` solution, but, alternatively, could be worth exploring a solution with `mapview` - check this out and see if it works for you:

```
library(mapview)

breaks <- c(1.0, 2139.2, 4277.5, 6415.8, 8554)

m_2005 <- mapview(map.temp[map.temp$year == 2005, ], 
                  zcol = "value", 
                  at = breaks, 
                  layer.name = "2005 - mt/ha")
m_2050 <- mapview(map.temp[map.temp$year == 2050, ], 
                  zcol = "value", 
                  at = breaks, 
                  layer.name = "2050 - mt/ha")
m_2080 <- mapview(map.temp[map.temp$year == 2080, ], 
                  zcol = "value", 
                  at = breaks, 
                  layer.name = "2080 - mt/ha")

sync(m_2005, m_2050, m_2080) # add ncol = 1, if you wish 1 column representation
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution. I knew (vaguely) about mapview but not about sync. I'll also post a bug report for the tmap developers.